# Creating another row based on differences of other rows

Tags: r

I have been stuck with this problem for a week or so now, and need some help.

My data looks like this:

| Apples | Bananas | Cherries | Date | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 5 | 20 | Date 1 | Store |
| 20 | 10 | 30 | Date 1 | Car |
| 30 | 50 | 15 | Date 1 | Home |
| 40 | 30 | 20 | Date 2 | Store |
| 45 | 20 | 10 | Date 2 | Car |
| 40 | 10 | 60 | Date 2 | Home |

I want to make another category under "Type" called, let's say, "Farm" which is the difference between Store, Car, and Home (or Farm = Store - Car - Home), which is calculated for every unique Date.

The result I would like is:

| Apples | Bananas | Cherries | Date | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 5 | 20 | Date 1 | Store |
| 20 | 10 | 30 | Date 1 | Car |
| 30 | 50 | 15 | Date 1 | Home |
| 40 | 30 | 20 | Date 2 | Store |
| 45 | 20 | 10 | Date 2 | Car |
| 40 | 10 | 60 | Date 2 | Home |
| -40 | -55 | -25 | Date 1 | Farm |
| -45 | -20 | -70 | Date 2 | Farm |

(The numbers are made up and are negative in this case, but not in my real dataset. Additionally, my dataset has more "fruit" columns)

I haven't tried much on R yet, because I don't know where to start. I exported the data to do the calculations manually. However, ideally, I would like for R to do the calculations before exporting to reduce a step.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: For Date 2 Bananas, 30 - 20 - 10 = 0, not -20. For Date 2 Cherries, 20-10-60 = -50, not -70. Right?

Comment: Yes, you're correct. I was trying (failing) to do some quick maths. Good catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
            Apples = c(10L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 45L, 40L),
           Bananas = c(5L, 10L, 50L, 30L, 20L, 10L),
          Cherries = c(20L, 30L, 15L, 20L, 10L, 60L),
              Date = c("Date 1","Date 1","Date 1",
                       "Date 2","Date 2","Date 2"),
              Type = c("Store", "Car", "Home", "Store", "Car", "Home")
)

library(tidyverse)
bind_rows(df,
          summarize(df, across(Apples:Cherries,  
                              ~.x[Type == "Store"] - sum(.x[Type != "Store"])), 
                        Type = "Farm", .by = Date))
```

Result

```
  Apples Bananas Cherries   Date  Type
1     10       5       20 Date 1 Store
2     20      10       30 Date 1   Car
3     30      50       15 Date 1  Home
4     40      30       20 Date 2 Store
5     45      20       10 Date 2   Car
6     40      10       60 Date 2  Home
7    -40     -55      -25 Date 1  Farm
8    -45       0      -50 Date 2  Farm
```

Comment: Thanks! This did almost exactly what I needed. I just switched "summarize" to "reframe".